# Override max-width from parent class

Tags: html, css

I am using a responsive grid layout for mobile and desktop sizes. My goal is to divide the footer in two rows and add a line between them that fit the whole size of the screen. However I have a container class with **max-width: 1700px** for desktop size so in order to fulfil my goal I create a class, intermediate-line **with max-width: none** (and also with initial) but still inherits the max-width of the container. here is my code

```
/********CSS*******/
.container{
   padding-right: 15px;
   padding-left: 15px;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
   max-width: 1170px;
}

@media(min-width: 48em){
   .container > .intermediate-line{
       max-width:none;
       border-top: solid 1px;  
   }
}
/******************/

/*******HtML*******/
<footer class="background-primary">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1-4">logo</div>
    <div class="col-1-4">address</div>
    <div class="col-1-4">Phone Number</div>
    <div class="col-1-4">Social Media</div>
  </div>

  <div class="intermediate-line"></div> 

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1-4">copyright</div>
    <div>Privacy Policy</div>
    <div>Terms of Use</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `none` is not a valid value for `max-width`. Have you tried `auto`?

Comment: How is `.intermediate-line` styled? If you remove its `max-width` you would expect it to be the width of its parent. Please show us the style you have for that. Better yet, provide a working example.

Comment: @Turnip yes I tried with many values including initial but it didn't have any effect, always inherits the container max-width along with its padding values.

Comment: @Moob if I remove the  max-width of the `.intermediate-line` it will inherit the container max-width, similarly it has the same effect if  I override the max-width with any other value. But if you look @codexy's answer the problem it's solved by tweaking the html code so the line spans the whole width of the screen larger than 1170px.

Comment: Even better, provide a working *minimal* example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make two containers and max-width of line 100% and it will stretch to whole screen no matter of container width

```css
.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 1170px;
}
.intermediate-line {
  max-width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid;
 }
.containerx {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 70px;
}
.intermediate-linex {
  max-width: auto;
  border-top: 1px solid;
 }
.containery {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 1170px;
}
.background-primaryy
{max-width: 180px;}
.intermediate-liney {
  max-width: initial;
  border-top: 1px solid;
 }
```

```html
<footer class="background-primary">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1-4">logo</div>
      <div class="col-1-4">address</div>
      <div class="col-1-4">Phone Number</div>
      <div class="col-1-4">Social Media</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="intermediate-line"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1-4">copyright</div>
      <div>Privacy Policy</div>
      <div>Terms of Use</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </footer>

<br><br>
<footer class="background-primaryx">
  <div class="containerx">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1-4">logo</div>
      <div class="col-1-4">address</div>
      <div class="col-1-4">Phone Number</div>
      <div class="col-1-4">Social Media</div>
    </div>
 
  <div class="intermediate-linex"></div>
 
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1-4">copyright</div>
      <div>Privacy Policy</div>
      <div>Terms of Use</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </footer>
<br><br>
<footer class="background-primaryy">
  <div class="containery">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1-4">logo</div>
      <div class="col-1-4">address</div>
      <div class="col-1-4">Phone Number</div>
      <div class="col-1-4">Social Media</div>
    </div>
 
  <div class="intermediate-liney"></div>
 
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1-4">copyright</div>
      <div>Privacy Policy</div>
      <div>Terms of Use</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </footer>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Do you know why I can't override the max-width value of the `intermediate-line` like this [example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_initial)

Comment: In this example red color is overriden with initial value, in this case it is black color which means that somewhere else (probably in body) color is set to be black and initial value is picking that style. If you put some width on footer, for example, and than set initial to max-width on intermediate-line it will pick footer's width, not containers

Comment: @Byron Aguirre, check my edited code. Basically, if you have five divs, the most inner one with value initial will pick up style from one of the outer divs if it is declared. If there is max-width only on container, it will pick that max-width. If it is on container and on one of the outer divs it will pick up max-width from the outer, not container. Feel free to ask if you do not understand something

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Bootstrap goes:

1. container
2. row
3. col-[size]-[n1 + n2 + n... = 12]

View Snippet in Full Page mode and resize down.

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>00A00</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
  <style>
    /********CSS*******/
    .container {
      padding-right: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      max-width: 1170px;
    }
    footer {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-bottom: 0 none transparent;
    }
    @media(min-width: 48em) {
      /*768px*/
      footer.row .left-division {
        border-right: 1px solid black;
      }
      footer.row {
        border-top: 1px solid black;
      }
    }
    /******************/
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <!--*******HtML*******-->

    <footer class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 left-division">
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='logo col-sm-6'>
            <img src='http://placehold.it/50x50/000/fff?text=LOGO'>
          </div>
          <address class='col-sm-6'>
            <div>Address</div>
            <div>Phone Number</div>
            </address>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div>Social Media</div>
          </div>
          <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div>copyright</div>
            <div>Privacy Policy</div>
            <div>Terms of Use</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: actually I not using bootstrap I am doing the grid system from scratch to get more familiar with responsive layout. what I can see is that is hard to override from the parent class I tried to override many child elements including the `intermediate-line` from the parent container and no luck. Do you what am I missing?

Comment: What is `.col-1-4`? What you are missing is the concept of inheritance? It's hard to tell with the amount of CSS given,